# Take an array and turn it into a new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
[timestamps => Array ( 
    [0] => 2013-07-25 18:02:48 
    [1] => 2013-07-25 19:12:07 
    [2] => 2013-07-25 19:13:09 
)
```

I need to turn it into this:

```
$date_accessed  = array(
    array( 'ID' => 1, 'date' => '2013-07-25', 'time' => '18:02:49' ),
    array( 'ID' => 2, 'date' => '2013-07-25', 'time' => '19:12:07' ),
    array( 'ID' => 3, 'date' => '2013-07-25', 'time' => '19:13:09' )
);
```

I am using this Wordpress function to generate the array:

```
get_user_meta( $user_id, '_last_login', true )
```

The value for the ID key is incremented and not derived from the timestamp array key. For example, to generate the ID value it can be done as $i=1...$i++.

I need to extract the date and time separately from sample array and assign the values to the date and time key.

I have tried but I just can't get it all pulled together.

Comment: Show us how you've tried

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $timestamps = array ('2013-07-25 18:02:48', '2013-07-25 19:12:07', '2013-07-25 19:13:09');
    $arr=array();
    $i=0;
    foreach($timestamps as $key=>$timestamp) {
        $time = explode(" ", $timestamp); //you better be sure its a timestamp
        $arr[$i] = array('ID' => $key, 'date'=>$time[0], 'time'=>$time[1]);
        $i++;
    }
    print_r($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$timestamps = array ('2013-07-25 18:02:48', '2013-07-25 19:12:07', '2013-07-25 19:13:09');

$newArr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($timestamps as $arr) {
    $datetime = new DateTime($arr);
    $newArr[$i]['ID']   = $i; // set index with $i
    $newArr[$i]['date'] = date_format($datetime, 'Y-m-d'); // get date
    $newArr[$i]['time'] = date_format($datetime, 'H:i:s'); // get time
    $i++;
}
```

#### Output

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'ID' => int 0
      'date' => string '2013-07-25' (length=10)
      'time' => string '18:02:48' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'ID' => int 1
      'date' => string '2013-07-25' (length=10)
      'time' => string '19:12:07' (length=8)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'ID' => int 2
      'date' => string '2013-07-25' (length=10)
      'time' => string '19:13:09' (length=8)
```

Comment: why are you running the dates through DateTime when they are already in the desired format to start with?

Comment: @Gordon I didnt understand you clearly. But date_format require `DateTime` format. Not acceptable string.

Comment: The original date strings are already in Y-m-d H:i:s format, so all you need to do is split them at the space. There is no need to parse them with DateTime first and them format then again. It's much costlier.

Comment: I know but i like to doing everything with original. It is datetime string and i did with DateTime format ;))

Answer (score 0):

```
$date_accessed = array();
foreach ($timestamps as $key => $value){
    $dt = explode(' ', $value);
    $date_accessed[] = array('ID' => $key, 'date' => $dt[0], 'time' => $dt[1]);
}
```